# What's in "standard system utilities" in the server install?

Tags: server, system-installation

My googlefu has failed me. What packages are part of the "standard system utilities" that is preselected during install?

TIA! (-:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What do you mean "standard system utilities"?

Comment: @zzzach By "preselected during install" he means during installation of the OS.  It's now one of the options on the "choose software to install" screen (where you select things like SSH, LAMP, DNS, etc.). For some reason, this option is preselected even on a minimal install, which is what lead me here...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I assume you mean on the software selection screen near the end of the install.

You can see the list of packages after install using tasksel

```
sudo tasksel --task-package standard
```

Your server will run fine with or without them and you can always install them later. They are all mostly convenience things like nano and ftp. If you want to save some space on your install unselect it and just install the utilities you want.

Here is the list for the 16.04 LTS release standard system utilities

```
manpages
dnsutils
bsdmainutils
psmisc
python3-gdbm
ufw
dosfstools
ed
telnet
powermgmt-base
ntfs-3g
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
iputils-tracepath
python3-update-manager
groff-base
python3-distupgrade
bind9-host
mtr-tiny
bash-completion
mlocate
tcpdump
geoip-database
install-info
irqbalance
language-selector-common
friendly-recovery
command-not-found
info
hdparm
man-db
lshw
update-manager-core
apt-transport-https
accountsservice
command-not-found-data
python3-commandnotfound
time
ltrace
parted
popularity-contest
strace
ftp
ubuntu-standard
lsof
```

Comment: How big is that? I think it's almost a gigabyte? Could it be? somewhere between 900 and 1100 MB of HDD space